# Vulnerabilidad en git: "CVE-2021-3711 for OpenSSL"

Tags: git, security

Estamos teniendo problemas con git, ya que nos da la vulnerabilidad Security CVE-2021-3711 con OpenSSL, y encuentro en internet mucha información sobre la causa pero no cómo solucionarla.

He visto que git no ha actualizado versión para solucionar esta vulnerabilidad. ¿Alguno ha conseguido quitarla de alguna forma?

Nos está bloqueando el desarrollo, ya que no nos permiten acceder a una VPN si no se soluciona.

Muchas gracias,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He abierto un ticket en git, y dan una solución temporal hasta que suban nueva versión que solucione esta incidencia, lo cual funcionó para mí.

Dicha solución consiste en indicar que me descargue el último snapshot de git que tienen colgado hasta que suban la siguiente versión que solucione dicha vulnerabilidad.

La ruta de la descarga con la solucion temporal es:
wingit.blob.core.windows.net/files/index.html)

Posteriormente hacen otra anotación al ticket, en la que indican que según la forma que tiene git de trabajar con openssl es imposible que se produzca tal vulnerabilidad, dejando entrever que la citada nueva versión que solucioné esta vulnerabilidad puede que nunca llegue.

Este es el ticket que puse en git y la respuesta completa:
https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3424

Comment: Describe brevemente _en la respuesta_ cuál es la solución temporal que te han dado.

Comment: La solución temporal que me han dado es que me descargue git desde un enlace que me dieron:  "The fixed OpenSSL binaries will be included in thee next release of Git for Windows. In the mean time you can try the latest snapshot" (enlace: https://wingit.blob.core.windows.net/files/index.html).

Comment: Por favor, pulsa en [edit] y pon lo que pusiste en el comentario como parte de la respuesta, para que sea más completa (y traduce el contenido en inglés, teniendo en cuenta que el idioma del sitio es el español). Lee [answer], en especial la sección _Ofrece contexto para los enlaces_.